# Can a function with gaps in domain be upper semi continuous at the point where there is a gap?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For example, consider $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ with $A = [0,1]\cup 2\cup [3,4]$ and $f$ defined as $f(x) = x$.

Then at $x=2$, for any $\epsilon >0$, since for and $\delta$ with $0<\delta<1$ there are are no $y\in B_\delta(x)$ with $f(y) > f(x) + \epsilon$, this function $f$ would be usc at $x=2$?

If there is an issue in the above, I'm thinking perhaps a problem lies in the fact that $A$ is perhaps not a topological space?

Thanks.

Comment: You are correct, it is upper semicontinuous.

BTW whenever you have a subset of a topological space it is itself a topological space in a canonical way, with the "subspace topology".

Comment: Thank you very much, and I appreciate the additional information about a subset of a topological space being a topological space with the"subspace topology"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comment, this function is indeed upper semi-continuous.